# How do I set up my own custom signet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, network, signet

Configuration: a Windows machine on a local WiFi network.
For classroom purposes I would like to have a custom Signet network so students can get used with Bitcoin Core and Send/Receive.

This is the bitcoin conf file I already created:

```
signet=1
signetchallenge=512100146aa4936a2dc8d8c26c3429a0c78017f974268d2f51ae

[signet]
rpcport=38332
rpcuser=tester
rpcpassword=tester
```

I used the [Signet wiki page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Signet#Custom_Signet) to get me started together with ChatGPT (since I use Windows and the Wiki page demonstrates it in Linux.

I think other nodes should use that same conf file but in my WiFi network they don't see each other. It's the first time I try Signet so probable I'm making some noob errors here.

Setting up an issuer to mine blocks is another difficulty; hope to get some insights on that too.

Thank you!